# How to combine intersection and union types

Tags: ecmascript-6, flowtype

Need to 'extend' the base type `Base` by the property `c`.
The following [code](https://flow.org/try/#0PQKgBAAgZgNg9gdzCYAoVBTAHgBzgJwBcxCBPHDMAQTAF4wByAQwEYGwAfRpgJgYG5MuAsTIUwAITqdGAIzYyGsvotkBmdlyUAWAelRjKEpgGdK9AN6owJchgBc1ADTWwTRwDsArgFtZGfBcAXxkrG0NHCRcbWU9ff0DUIMEDOzAAEQCASwA3DAATaTCwAGNHWTg4GAwmD0EQrmMzFJK4DxNiKGkACixHTPxcgoBKOgA+MGKsqF6AOkM6WnpmNlGrAEgsWaZpNUEbINdpuYWl5fkGNdRN2dld-bBDoKA):

```
/* @flow */

export type A = 'a1' | 'a2';
export type B = | 'b1' | 'b2' | 'b3' | 'b4';


type Base = {
  type: A,
  a: number,
} | {
  type: B,
  b: number,
};

type Derived = {
  c: boolean;
} & Base; // #17

const f = (x: Derived) => { // #19
  if(x.type === 'a1') {
    x.a = 3; // #21
  }
  if(x.type === 'b1') {
    x.b = 3; // #24
  }
}
```

results by

```
19: const f = (x: Derived) => {
                  ^ intersection type. This type is incompatible with
17: } & Base;
        ^ union: object type(s)
21:     x.a = 3;
     ^ assignment of property `a`. Property cannot be assigned on any member of intersection type
21:     x.a = 3;
     ^ intersection
24:     x.b = 3;
     ^ assignment of property `b`. Property cannot be assigned on any member of intersection type
24:     x.b = 3;
     ^ intersection
```

Is there any solution other than to add the same prop `c` to both of member of the union? Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could reverse this and make `Derived` the union of `BaseA` and `BaseB` and add the common attribute with an intersection for both of the bases ([working example](https://flow.org/try/#0PQKgBAAgZgNg9gdzCYAoVBTAHgBzgJwBcxCBPHDMAQTAF4wByAQwEYGwAfRpgJgYG5MuAsTIUwAITqdGAIzYyGsvotkBmdlyUAWAejGUJTAM6V6Ab1RgwAYwBcYWXDgwMTAHaCAvoNQHJJhg09EamYABkYJbWTA7uAK4AtrIY+AA0ViTkGA5UGT762QGmUiGBEVGZsnFJKemZBg4S+b7+ACKpAJYAbhgAJtKhQTJDEr42cO7GxFDSABRYDh34Pf0AlHQAfJXWWAB0NtKE+PEYgtadUAt7-rR33GwblgCQ+0zSaudgXpmX17f3JSPSqvPayD5fH5eIA)):

```
/* @flow */

export type A = 'a1' | 'a2';
export type B = | 'b1' | 'b2' | 'b3' | 'b4';

type Base = {
  c: boolean;
};

type BaseA = Base & {
  a: number,
  type: A,
};

type BaseB = Base & {
  b: number,
  type: B,
};

type Derived = BaseA | BaseB;

const f = (x: Derived) => {
  x.c = true;
  if(x.type === 'a1') {
    x.a = 3;
  }
  if(x.type === 'b1') {
    x.b = 3;
  }
}
```